# How to set the icon and channels for IE9's “Pinned Sites”

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

IE9 beta appeared today, and one of the most prominent features is Pinned Sites: drag an url/favorite/whatever to the taskbar, and you create a “Pinned Site”, which follows some custom rules (favicon presented in application chrome, back/fwd button turn the color of the favicon!).

What is interesting is that:
1) Some sites are pinned to the taskbar not with their favicon, but rather with a bigger icon, à la iOS home screen favorite. How can I set this?

2) Developers can set “channels” or “jump lists” for even quicker access that are presented when (right-?)clicking the icon. How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [article from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg131029%28VS.85%29.aspx) should tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score 1):

Hanselman also did a good writeup about [pinned sites](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE9SiteSpecificBrowsersAndAddingYourOwnJumpListItemsToPinnedTabs.aspx).